# Pyperclip - IDLE 3 on Ubuntu

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu, pyperclip

I am new to python and having trouble installing `pyerclip` on ubuntu. The terminal shows following error.

```
pip3 install pyperclip
Collecting pyperclip
Installing collected packages: pyperclip
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 784, in install
    **kwargs
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 851, in install
    self.move_wheel_files(self.source_dir, root=root, prefix=prefix)
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 1064, in move_wheel_files
    isolated=self.isolated,
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 345, in move_wheel_files
    clobber(source, lib_dir, True)
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 316, in clobber
    ensure_dir(destdir)
  File "/home/xanthus/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 83, in ensure_dir
    os.makedirs(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 241, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyperclip'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need superuser access.  Do a `sudo pip3 install pyperclip`.

Comment: Thanks with sudo pip3 install pyperclip. i can install it but while importing it in IDLE3 there is this error    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    pyperclip.copy('Hello World')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 574, in lazy_load_stub_copy
    return copy(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pyperclip/__init__.py", line 284, in __call__
    raise PyperclipException(EXCEPT_MSG)
pyperclip.PyperclipException: 
    Pyperclip could not find a copy/paste mechanism for your system.

Comment: For future reference, googling the specific error usually will bring you the solution or at least a few steps closer.  Here's what yielded in the first results from Google and should fix your issue on Linux: https://pyperclip.readthedocs.io/en/latest/introduction.html#not-implemented-error